# unit testing Method calling from another method in c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

**Please Help me on this:**

In here I need to call this `Add(...)` method through the `Calling(...)` method in `MyAnotherClass`. When I `Assert` it gives an error. Please show me the path.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public List<int> number = new List<int>();

    public void Add(int a, int b)
    {   
        int c = a + b;
        number.Add(c);
    }
 }

public class MyAnotherClass
{
    public void CallingMethod(int c, int d)
    {          
        MyClass mc = new MyClass();
        mc.Add( c, d);
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        MyAnotherClass mac = new MyAnotherClass();

        MyClass mc = new MyClass();

        mc.Add(2, 3);
        Assert.AreEqual(5, mc.number[0]);// **this work fine** 

        mac.CallingMethod(2, 3);
        Assert.AreEqual(5, mc.number[0]);// **but this not**
    }
}
```

Thanks

**Begginer**

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? What value does the second `mc.number[0]` provide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class, MyAnotherClass returns void, and does not provide a public property from which you can retrieve data from the inner MyClass.

You'd want something like:

```
public class MyAnotherClass
{
   public MyClass mc = new MyClass();
   public void CallingMethod(int c, int d)
   {
      mc.Add(c, d);
   }
}
```

Then, in your test class, you'd call mac.mc.number[0] in the comparison.

Answer (score 3):

You never update the object referenced by "mc" in the second case, but a new object with a reference called "mc" in the "MyAnotherClass" class.

Answer (score 1):

You have two instances of `MyClass`, one you instantiate in the test, the other in `MyAnotherClass`. If you want to have only one instance you should pass it to the constructor of `MyAnotherClass` or make an argument of `CallingMethod`

```
public class MyAnotherClass
{
    private readonly MyClass _myClass;

    public MyAnotherClass(MyClass myClass)
    {
        _myClass = myClass;
    }

    public void CallingMethod(int c, int d)
    {          
        _myClass.Add( c, d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the "mc" object, defined in CallingMethod, outside of its scope. If MyAnotherClass were to get an instance of MyClass in its constructor (for example), reference it using a property, and then update it, and test this new reference - it would work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the method makes any sense ,

or could you told me what it can do?

```
public void CallingMethod(int c, int d)
{          
    MyClass mc = new MyClass();
    mc.Add( c, d);
}
```

You'd better post your completely source for this method.

Or , if you can you could change the method like

```
public int CallingMethod(int c, int d)
{          
    MyClass mc = new MyClass();
    mc.Add( c, d);
    return mc.number[0];
}
```

Then , you can test it more easy.